# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification is not called sometimes

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I wrote code for iCloud key-value Store

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyValueStoreChanged:)
                                                 name:NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification
                                               object:nil];
    LOG(@"sync");
    [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize];
```

When I delete app and reinstall it, observer method is called usually, but sometimes not called.

Why? Just the network problem?

Comment: I'm see a similar issue where the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification never seems to get fired on the very first reinstall of an app after installation, no matter how long I wait. But closing the app (not putting it in background) and simply launching it a second time, seems to work and NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification
 starts firing properly from there on out.

Comment: Filed with apple @ bugreport.apple.com, 12394404 - NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore notifications do not fire on first app launch

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification wasn't triggering on the first launch after install, no matter how long I waited. Setting an initial key in the NSUBiquitousKeyValueStore seemed to solve this.

Immediately after adding the observer to the default store, I call:

```
[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] setString:@"testValue" forKey:@"testKey"];
[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize];
```

I use different keys (i.e. not *testKey*) for the actual data I want to sync.